# How to check condition for every month between two date

Tags: sql-server

I am working on the stack exchange database for a project.(https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new)
I would like to know TOP 10 users who have posting every month between there are registered in database.
I have tried this but I am lost :

```
SELECT TOP 10 
   Propriétaire 
FROM 
   (SELECT 
      count(Mois) AS nbMoisPosté, 
      datediff(month, création, getdate()) AS nbMoisTotal, 
      Propriétaire 
    FROM
       (SELECT 
          count(Posts.Id) AS nbPosts,
          month(Posts.creationDate) AS Mois,
          year(Posts.creationDate) AS Année
          Posts.ownerUserId AS Propriétaire,
          Users.creationDate AS création
       FROM 
          Posts, Users
       WHERE 
          Users.Id = Posts.ownerUserId
       GROUP BY 
          Posts.ownerUserId, 
          Mois, 
          Année, 
          création) compte
   GROUP BY 
      datediff(month, création, getdate()), 
      Propriétaire) nbMois
WHERE nbMoisPosté = nbMoisTotal
```

It doesn't work (syntax error) but I don't understand my mistake.
Thanks.

Comment: Share the error please

Comment: the error : "Incorrect syntax near 'Posts'"

Comment: Clear up your code and you will see you are missing a comma near the word Posts.  Funny how error messages work....

Comment: Which word Posts?

Comment: @Mattasse You have to put a little effort in, you know. There are less than 10 "Posts" words. Shouldnt be too hard to look.

Comment: You are missing a comma after `year(Posts.creationDate) AS Année` for starters... and secondly, get rid of those old style joins. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try correcting these issues.

Please make sure you post your error messages

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    Propriétaire 
FROM 

    (
    SELECT 
        count(Mois) AS nbMoisPosté, 
        datediff(month, création, getdate()) AS nbMoisTotal, 
        Propriétaire 
    FROM
        (
        SELECT 
            count(Posts.Id) AS nbPosts, 
            month(Posts.creationDate) AS Mois,
            year(Posts.creationDate) AS Année   --MISSING COMMA
            Posts.ownerUserId AS Propriétaire,
            Users.creationDate AS création
        FROM 
            Posts, 
            Users
        WHERE 
            Users.Id = Posts.ownerUserId
        GROUP BY 
            Posts.ownerUserId, 
            Mois, --GROUP BY THE FUNCTION month(Posts.creationDate)
            Année, --GROUP BY THE FUNCTION year(Posts.creationDate)
            création

            ) compte
    GROUP BY 
        datediff(month, création, getdate()), 
        Propriétaire
        ) nbMois
WHERE 
    nbMoisPosté = nbMoisTotal
```

Comment: You can only use column names like this in the ORDER BY clause, not in the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Thanks, I have many trouble with the ORDER BY clause. It's work now

Comment: Don't forget to tick your chosen answer.